# Laravel setup on Mac in XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, laravel, xampp

When I try to run laravel app using XAMPP localhost, it gives me a white screen of death. However, when I use `artisan serve`, the app works fine.

Here are the steps that I did:
1. I installed composer globally. 
2. Install laravel using the zip file and also through composer. Through zip file, I ran `composer install`.

When I run `localhost/my_app/public`, it gives me blank white screen.

Seeing previous answers, I did some things

Added this to bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
```

On running `which php`, I get this:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php
```

Not able to figure out what would be the exact issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the `storage` directory access rights. You can change it's mod to `777` or assign the user(with which apache runs in XAMPP) the ownership of the `storage` directory.

Here is an example of the command to use:

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Similarly, for assigning ownership:

`sudo chown storage [user]:[group]`

Comment: Where do I find the storage directory?

Comment: @phantomphoenix the `storage` directory is at the root of the laravel project

Answer (score 0):

have u tried pointing to htdocs and run ?

```
 composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

then

```
chmod -R 777 your_laravel_folder_path/storage
```

finally

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

If you trying in XAMPP then your_laravel_folder_path will
`/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER` . That folder contains `storage` directory.